# Destructuring an object with useState

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

I am getting this Error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

when destructuring ...vaults (object) inside setVaults.

Code:

```
  const [vaults, setVaults] = useState();

  const name = 'something'
  const totalSupply = 155000
  const totalBorrowed = 55050
  const capUtilRate = 0
  setVaults(...vaults, {[name]: {totalSupply, totalBorrowed, capUtilRate}})
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try this --> `setVaults({...vaults, {[name]: {totalSupply, totalBorrowed, capUtilRate}}})`

Comment: I am getting  property assigned expected on this graph parenthesis  {[name]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial state is undefined, and thus, not iterable. It seems your state is an object. You should use a functional state update as well. Remove the curly brackets around the property you are trying to set.

```
const [vaults, setVaults] = useState({});

...

const name = 'something';
const totalSupply = 155000;
const totalBorrowed = 55050;
const capUtilRate = 0;

setVaults(vaults => ({
  ...vaults, // <-- spread previous state
  [name]: {  // <-- create new object reference
     totalSupply,
     totalBorrowed,
     capUtilRate,
  },
}));
```

Comment: yes I was doing that but was getting another error, in the end watching your code I understood it was because I didn't put the code inside a callback: setVaults(...vaults, {[name]: {totalSupply, totalBorrowed, capUtilRate}}). Thank you